# Rails 3 autocomplete gem with belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, associations

I am using the [rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) and it works neat when using it for fields that exist in the model.  However, I have been trying to use it for associations and I fail to see how to make it work. So let's explain what I have:

**Models**:

```
class Receipt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :receipts
end
```

**Controller**

```
class Admin::ReceiptsController < AdminController
 autocomplete :user, :name
  def index
    @receipts = Receipt.all
  end
  def show
    @receipt = Receipt.find_by_id(params[:id])
  end
  def edit
    @receipt = Receipt.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

**View (form)**:

```
<%= form_for(@receipt, :url => admin_receipt_path, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
 <div class="clearfix">
  <%= f.label :value, "Value($)" %>
  <div class="input"><%= f.text_field :value %></div>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix">
  <%= f.label :user_id, "User" %>
  <div class="input">
   <%= f.autocomplete_field :user_id, autocomplete_user_name_admin_receipts_path %>
  </div>
 </div>
.....
```

The thing is... I am able to fetch user names, but I want to actually store the user id in there.  The same way I would like to show the name when the admin tries to edit an existing receipt with a user associated.  Something that I am able to do with this drop down:

```
<div class="clearfix">
 <%= f.label :user_id, "User" %>
 <div class="input"><%= f.select :user_id, @users.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },{:prompt => 'Select a User'} %></div>
</div>
```

I am failing to see how would I do this with this gem....

Comment: Where's the code for your controller?

Comment: Added. Even though I believe that doesn't give many information for the problem I am trying to solve...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan Bates did a screencast on this. Clean and well explained

[Screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association-revised)

If you don't feel like subscribing try torrent

Comment: Can't you just describe his method?